# Trailing border lines in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

When I scroll horizontally left to right, some trailing border lines appear in Chrome only. Please look at the screenshot for visual demonstration. How can I get rid of these lines from appearing when I scroll?

[image]

Comment: Could you post a URL that demonstrates this behavior?

Comment: A url or at least some CSS and possibly HTML would help us help you a lot. I was just dealing with a similar issue, are you using css transformations or transitions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without any examples of anything I would say add

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

to the container there assuming its something like .header

Comment: Is there any alternatives? For some reason, the solution works on my local server, but on live server. Strange.

Comment: It appears to be only working on Mac Chrome browser, not windows.

Comment: I kind of got it fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Ginn. I had to move the border from th to tr to solve this issue. It's kind of strange. But your solution did fix it for Mac Chrome browser. Thanks.